# Restore Oracle with RMAN for unknown database

Tags: database, oracle, rman

I was given a set of files (one file with extension .arc and others with .bas). These are Oracle backup files produced by RMAN utility. Now I need to restore these files to a new Oracle instance. Got no idea how to do that after searching for answers for a whole day.

Any helping hand will be very much appreciated.

Comment: hopefully helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4213522/how-to-import-a-oracle-11g-rman-backupset-on-a-new-database-server?rq=1

Comment: I have run the following script but error
run{
restore controlfile from "/home/oracle/oracle_backup/xxxxxx.arc";
restore spfile from "/home/oracle/oracle_backup/xxxxxx.arc";
alter database mount;
restore database;
recover database;
}

Comment: Did you ever use rman before? Do you also have the logfile from the backup process available?

Comment: I am new to rman. I have only got the .arc and .bas files and nothing else. Is it possible to restore database with only these files?

Comment: Are you trying to clone from prod to non-prod?